# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS running mdadm 16 x 8TB Raid 6 - Is it possible to upgrade individual disks and use the space immediately without using LVM?

Tags: ubuntu, mdadm, raid6

Some more background... I have 4 realtime arrays (always running for me to use) - the 2 big important arrays (40TB [20TB used] and 112TB [105TB used] are being backed up onto a 16 x 8TB Raid6 array (112TB free total storage - and as you can see, I have more to backup than I have space for).  So, I need more storage...

My nicer solution was to buy another SuperMicro 24bay JBOD but since after covid, prices have doubled the cheaper method right now, ... is to upgrade my drives.  BUT, I can't afford 16 x 16TB Exos drives at the same time... that's pretty pricey for a home server.  :)

So, what triggered me trying to find a way to upgrade all this?

I did purchase 3 16TB Exos yesterday.  I ran the following commands on the backup array...

```
#UPGRADE AN ARRAY *******************************************************
#FIRST ADD SPARES
mdadm /dev/md4 --add /dev/sdan  (a 16TB drive)
mdadm /dev/md4 --add /dev/sdao  (a 16TB drive)

#SECOND REPLACE DISKS (2 at a time)  replace 2 8TB drives with 16TB drives.
mdadm /dev/md4 --replace /dev/sdah /dev/sdai --with /dev/sdan /dev/sdao
```

---

Question #1: I am not using LVM.  Just a normal mdadm raid6 with a ext4 file system on top.  SO, my assumptions are... I can't use the extra space until ALL 8TB drives are upgraded to 16TB...
Question #1: Is this correct?

---

I was thinking... an alternative would be... once I get 9 x 16TB drives I could create a new array and copy everything from this 16 x 8TB array directly into the 9 x 16TB array as they are the same sizes and THEN I could just grow the array which I have done before...  Once I have the 9 disk array.. it's easy to add to it...

```
mdadm --grow --raid-devices=10 --backup-file=/root/md4_grow.bak /dev/md4
```

and then...

```
resize2fs /dev/md4
```

---

So, I just don't know the limitations of mdadm.  I know in my synology nas I can hybrid upgrade and get full use of any drive right away... but, I prefer mdadm even if I can't have hybrid control of the filesystem.  I guess I could add LVM on top of the raid6... but, I have never used that before... unsure if I could convert the current array I have now to LVM or if I would have to wipe everything out.  It IS a backup array... so, I can technically destroy it... BUT, the scary thing then becomes... I don't have a backup anymore.  What if my main arrays fail while I am rebuilding this new array?   Then I would lose gobs of data.

I know raid is not a backup, but this backup array is turned off most of the time.  It's only turned on for the backup and then turned off again.

For the super important data... I have it copy pasted onto a few 10TB Exos drive not in a raid and stuck in a box "just in case" something happens.  Sadly, I have to pick and choose what to backup in that way because I have too much data to backup properly... so, my backup array is the only thing close to the size needed to backup the realtime arrays...

---

Hypothetical Question #2: Let's say I finally --replace --with all my 16 x 8TB IronWolfs with 16 x 16TB Exos drives...  do I just run

```
resize2fs /dev/md4
```

and mdadm will see... "Hey, you're only using 8TB of the 16TB!!!!   Let's fix that!!!" and proceeds to expand to fill ALL the space?   Or do I have to do other commands once all the drives are upgraded?

I read that grow can take a size but... I've never used that... I've only used grow to ADD another drive to the array ... going from --raid-devices=9 to --raid-devices=10 for example... and then running

```
resize2fs /dev/md4
```

to get the new found space...

---

Thoughts from more experienced users than myself?

(thank you Gerald for formatting the code, it's been years since I asked a question and forgot about that).